# Change viewtype between listview and gridview and keep data Android

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have a working note-taking app currently using a listview. I want the user to be able to switch to a gridview. The switch is not the problem as I could just load a different layout file with the different view, but I want their current notes in the listview to be transferred over to the gridview notes upon the switch. Is there a way to access each notes contents using a for each loop and then add the contents to the gridview using something like `gridviewitem.add(listviewNoteContents);`

The issue I'm seeing with this is how would I send the note data between the 2 views if I'm loading 2 layout files. The note contents are stored in the SQLite database, but I don't want to have to query the database everytime I switch views as it seems inefficient compared to just getting the note's contents and adding them to a note in a different view.

Comment: What is the current viewControl to display the `ListView` or `GridView` there? Are you using ListView or RecylerView ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's ListView but how can I doublecheck?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456602/5973946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I have done before that I know works is to put your data into a `RecyclerView` and switch the layout manager between a `LinearLayoutManager` and a `GridLayoutManager`.  The adapter doesn't change so the data isn't affected.  The adapter can have different view types based on the current layout manager.

Comment: So I tried something different, but still following the information you gave about how the adapter doesn't change so the data isn't affected and you're right. I created a new xml layout file with a gridview, and in my onCreate method I called the new xml file and it put all of my previous notes into a gridview. It was 2 lines of code. Thanks!